# Getting current info song in macOS Catalina (Music.app)

Tags: objective-c, swift, macos, cocoa

Now that iTunes has been replaced by Music, how should I get current song's info (title, artist, album, artwork, length, current position etc.)? ScriptingBridge doesn't seem to work for Music.app. Running AppleScript inside the app just throws an error: `Not authorized to send Apple events to Music.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of Mac OS are you using ?

If you're using 10.14 or above, you should give your application explicit permission to send apple events to Music.app (or any other application).

You can do that from the "Security & Privacy" pane of System Preferences. 
Choose "Automation" of the left and see if your application is listed but not checked.

There's also the [AEDeterminePermissionToAutomateTarget](https://www.felix-schwarz.org/blog/2018/08/new-apple-event-apis-in-macos-mojave) API that allows your application to ask the user for permission

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Tried that approach, but the function returns not authorized (-1743). The prompt to approve does not appear. I have also added the usage string in Info.plist. The app does not appear in Security & Privacy at Automation. I have also tried `tccutil reset AppleEvents`

Comment: ooks like I had to enable "Apple Events" in "Resource Access" in Signing & Capabilities. Didn't see this anywhere in the documentation though...